# sorting doesn't work, datatable in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've got a problem with sorting my table. When I click on my table header, my table data don't sort. Even with using the *"show 10/25/50 entries"* and also the search bar.

I tried very long but seems not working. Here is my code. I don't is sit the plugin problem or my coding problem. I've tried many ways from the internet but all dont work. I'm running xampp locally with internet connection.

```js
$(".contentContainer").css("min-height", $(window).height());

$("textarea").css("height", $(window).height() - 110);

$("textarea").keyup(function() {

  $.post("updatediary.php", {
    diary: $("textarea").val()
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#topContainer {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#topRow {
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#topRow h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.marginTop {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 300%;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #B0D1FB;
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

,
marginBottom {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.appstoreImage {
  width: 250px;
}

.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">

        <a class="navbar-brand">IT Services</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
      
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       
         <ul class= "navbar-nav nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="mainpage.php">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="input.php">New Input</a></li>
          <li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log Out</a></li>
         
         
        </div>

      </div>       
       </div> 
  
      <div class="container">
     <div class="jumpbotron">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <td>Date</td>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <td>Details</td>
          <td>Status</td>
          <td>ticket id</td>
          <td>Actions</td>
          
         </tr>
        
        </thead>
        
      <?php  
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        {  
         
         $date=$row[2];
         $subject=$row[3];
         $detail=$row[4];
         $status=$row[5];
         $tickid=$row[0];
      
        ?> 
        
        <tbody method="post">
         
         <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($date); ?></td>
         <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($subject); ?></td>
         <td class="col-sm-2"><?php print_r($detail); ?> </td>
         <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($status); ?></td>
         <td class="col-md-1"><?php echo $tickid ; ?></td>
         <td class="col-md-1"><a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $tickid; ?>" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Details</td>
         
        </tbody>
        
        
        <?php } ?> 
       </table>
     </div>
     </div>
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
      </body>
```

Comment: can i know what tags i m missing?

Comment: Multiple ways to do that: 1. Use the issue panel of your IDE 2. Use this tool: https://validator.w3.org/ or this http://htmlhint.com/ 3. Use HTML hinters using npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlhint) 4. Use your brain! **Note:** Not sure what it will do it you mix PHP code with the HTML but it's possible.

Comment: I have added all the missing tags. But my table still not sorting when i click on the header

Answer (score 2):

- Change `td` elements to `th` in `thead`
- Take `tbody` out of `while` loop
- Add table row `tr` element inside `while` loop to enclose table cells

Answer (score 0):

I think you must clean up your code a little bit like @Gyrocode.com said. Code below works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>ticket id</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- start to loop here -->
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">10/04/2017</td>
      <td class="col-md-1">ABC</td>
      <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
      <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
      <td class="col-md-1">1546546</td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">11/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">DEF</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">5646156</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">12/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">ZXY</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">454658</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">OPQ</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">56446</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">ggg</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">52527</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">rtr</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">2577</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">rtfe</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">7254</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">rggthg</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">7527</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">frgbf</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">52727</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">grege</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">5872</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
           <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">13/04/2017</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">gtehtehte</td>
        <td class="col-sm-2">blablabla</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">Oke</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">5872</td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><a href="#" id="submit">Details</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end loop -->
    <tbody>
</table>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

Cleanup you your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="navbar-header">

    <a class="navbar-brand">IT Services</a>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="navbar-nav nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="mainpage.php">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="input.php">New Input</a></li>
        <li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumpbotron">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <th>Details</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>ticket id</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody method="post">

        <?php  
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        {  
         
         $date=$row[2];
         $subject=$row[3];
         $detail=$row[4];
         $status=$row[5];
         $tickid=$row[0];
      
        ?>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <?php print_r($date); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <?php print_r($subject); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
              <?php print_r($detail); ?> </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <?php print_r($status); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <?php echo $tickid ; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $tickid; ?>" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Details</td>
         
        
       </tr>
        
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```